# Find MySql specific key constraints

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a question: When I am manipulating data in my mysql database, it gives   some errors such as

> Duplicate entry '' for key 'UNIQ_99719D5877153098',

...
My question is: "How can I find out that what exactly the key UNIQ_99719D5877153098 or any other keys with this code pattern is?"

How can I find out the key constraints, the table that this constraint is defined on it, etc from the key codes mentioned in the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/table-constraints-table.html)

```
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
WHERE CONSTRAINT_NAME = 'UNIQ_99719D5877153098';
```